# Создание функции для типовых задач

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, select, prototype, функции

Есть следующий код:

```
        $('.approve_imgform select#img_propertyrelease').selectpicker('deselectAll');
        var allimagepropertiesoptions = [];
        allimageproperties.push({
          'id':imageid,
          'options':imageprops
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < allimageproperties.length; ++i) {
          $('select#img_propertyrelease option').each(function() {
            optionval = $(this);
            for(var j = 0; j < allimageproperties[i]['options'].length; ++j) {
                if(optionval.val() == allimageproperties[i]['options'][j]) {
                  optionval.attr('selected', true);
                }
            }
          });
          for(var k = 0; k < allimageproperties[i]['options'].length; ++k) {
              allimagepropertiesoptions.push(allimageproperties[i]['options'][k]);
          }
        }
        var propCount = compressArray(allimagepropertiesoptions);
        var selectedImages = $('.grid .grid-item img.selected').length;
        $('.approve_imgform select#img_propertyrelease option').removeClass();
        for(var c = 0; c < propCount.length; ++c) {
          if(propCount[c]['count'] == selectedImages){
              $('.approve_imgform select#img_propertyrelease option[value="'+propCount[c]['value']+'"]').addClass('common');
          }
          else if(propCount[c]['count'] < selectedImages) {
              $('.approve_imgform select#img_propertyrelease option[value="'+propCount[c]['value']+'"]').addClass('some');
          }
        }
        var allimagepropertiesoptions = [];
        $('.approve_imgform select#img_propertyrelease').selectpicker('refresh');
```

По выполнению код собирает инфу в массив (allimageproperties), выделяет нужные элементы списка, считает дубли в массиве и стилизует список.

Таких списков у меня несколько (меняется массив allimageproperties, селектор списка, массив опций allimagepropertiesoptions, массив дублей propCount), хотел написать функцию, используя которую можно сделать код выше типовым. Не знаю с чего начать.